# Cannot retrieve the HTML Dom object

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I am using IE11 for this since that is my companys standard browser.

I am working on a solution to catch the paste event when pasting a screen dump into the web application. So far so good but after I have pasted the image I would like to change the size. Preferable before actually so I don't get a jumping application.

I have create a jsfiddle where you can see the entire test application: http://jsfiddle.net/e5f5gLan/3/

Do like this when running the jsfiddle:

1. Make a screen shot
2. Put the marker in the red square
3. Press Ctrl + v

Now the intention is that the pasted image should become 100px x 100px in size. It doesn't.

The problem is that I am not getting hold of the DOM object so I can set the style/size of the image.

The significant part is at the end of the javascript (I guess...):

```
var image_container = document.getElementById('pastearea');
var image = image_container.getElementsByTagName("img");
image[0].setAttribute("style", "width: 100px; height: 100px");
```

First of all, I imagined that the img element would become part of an array and that I should access the only img-element using image[0]. But then I get the error "Not possible to get setAttribute for a reference that is undefined or null. " (freely translated from Swedish...)

Ok, perhaps it understands it is only one element and just returns an object that isn't an array. So I changed the last row above to:

```
image.setAttribute("style", "width: 100px; height: 100px");
```

Then I get that setAttribute is not supported by the object.

If I create an HTML page with similar structure (img inside div) and just tries to change the size, then it works. Check out this one (click the button to shrink the image): http://jsfiddle.net/m4kzd7jp/3/

How can I change change the size of the image before or after I have pasted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I added the style and it worked to keep it 100px height/width.

```
 #pastearea img { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

I tested your code and the filelist was always 0.   If you want to handle this through code, here's what I was using in our project.  basically you should be looping items not files and checking if it is a file.

```
            function (e) {
                var clip = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
                if (clip) {
                    var preInsert = getData(); // this pulled the input box text or div html

                    for (var i = 0; i < clip.items.length; i++) {
                        var item = clip.items[i];

                        if (item.kind == "file" &&
                            item.type.indexOf('image/') !== -1) {
                            var fr = new FileReader();
                            fr.onloadend = function () {
                                if (preInsert == getData()) // if nothing changed, we'll handle it otherwise it was already handled
                                    setData(fr.result);
                            };
                            var data = item.getAsFile();
                            fr.readAsDataURL(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This area shows what I was doing in angular to get/set

```
            var getSelection = function() {
                if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().rangeCount > 0) //FF,Chrome,Opera,Safari,IE9+
                {
                    return window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
                }
                else if (document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
                {
                    return document.selection.createRange();
                }
                return null;
            }

            var isInputTextarea = false; // I was being more generic in my angular directive

            var getData = function () {
                if (isInputTextarea)
                    return $element.val();

                return $element.html();
            };

            var setData = function (src) {
                if (isInputTextarea) {
                    $element.val(function (index, value) {
                        return value + " " + "<img src='" + src + "'>";
                    });
                }
                else {
                    var selection = getSelection(); // I presume we have focus at this point, since it is a paste event
                    if (selection) {
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.src = src;
                        selection.insertNode(img);
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out tomorrow when back at the windows machine. Do you know if your suggestion works with both IE11, FF and Chrome?

Comment: Yes, it should work in all of them.  I tested at one point IE8-11, lastest FF, & Chrome

Comment: The question was about IE11 but when playing around it seems like it works OOB for Firefox, not Chrome though: http://jsfiddle.net/2s4vy5np/2/

Comment: Chrome is my main browser, so it's always my default test.   Do you see any errors in the console?  it seems to work for me using your jsfiddle?

Comment: Tested in Chrome 46.0.2490.71
FireFox 41.0.2
IE 11.0.9600.18053

Comment: I tried your code in IE11. I stripped your code down to just show what is not working here: http://jsfiddle.net/xh5u6jpa/  It seems like e.originalEvent.clipboardData is not instantiated. Using IE 11.0.9600.18015CO (I cannot upgrade, corporate stuff). Did you get the jsfiddle a couple of comments above to work in IE really? I will try to see if something have happened with the clipboard between mine and your IE version.

Comment: Forgot to answer your question. Error message in console is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clipboardData' of undefined"

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  I write mostly angular code, so it was one piece I missed when I adjusted for you.   Remove the originalEvent, angular overrides and you wouldn't need that.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Clip becomes undefined: http://jsfiddle.net/xh5u6jpa/3/  Do you get this code to work in your IE11?

Comment: You are trying to read it before you pasted it.  getData is just making sure you it wasn't handled by the browser before we went to process.   I believe this happens with urls rather than pasted content.  The setData will need to CREATE an img tag and put that into the element.   I'll add more code to show.

Comment: Thanks! However, "clip" is never instantiated so nothing inside if (clip) { } will ever be executed. It feels like an important step to fix to get the entire code to work. Check out this and you get the point: http://jsfiddle.net/xh5u6jpa/4/ Do you really get an object instantiated there using IE11?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, must have been an angular/jquery thing.   You just need to update the code to    var clip = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;

Comment: Ok, so the actual questions was answered properly, thanks! But the code you provided doesn't work. Not sure if it is because you include Angular. Here is the snippet of code catching the image from the clipboard and in this case I am retrieving it as base64: http://jsfiddle.net/xh5u6jpa/6/

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't easy to pull this from angular.  But at least it gave you enough of an idea of how to get it working.